# How to evaluate the sum $\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-i)$?

Tags: summation

How would I go about solving this summation?

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-i)$$

So far I have:

Using variable substitution

let ${k = j - i}$

$$ \sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-i) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n-i} k$$

$$S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - i)-2 + (n - i) - 1 + (n - i) $$

$$S = (n-i) + (n-i)-1 + (n-i)-2 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1$$

$$2S = (n-i+1)(n-i)$$

$$S = 1/2(((n-i+1)(n-i))) $$

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-i) = 1/2(((n-i+1)(n-i))) $$

Am I following this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your approach by splitting the sum you can use $\sum_{k=1}^m k = \frac 12 m(m+1)$ twice as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-i)
& = & \sum_{j=i+1}^n j - \sum_{j=i+1}^n i \\
& = & \underbrace{\sum_{j=i+1}^n j + \sum_{j=1}^{\color{blue}{i}} j}_{\sum_{\color{blue}{j=1}}^n j}- \sum_{j=1}^{\color{blue}{i}} j  - i\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1 \\
& = & \sum_{\color{blue}{j=1}}^n j - \sum_{j=1}^{\color{blue}{i}} j  - i\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1 \\
& = & \frac 12 n(n+1) - \frac 12 i(i+1) - i(n-i)\\
& \stackrel{some \, algebra}{=} & \frac 12(n-i)(n+1-i)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the solution, but I had to resort to writing out the sequence. I'm very grateful for your answer. Could you just let me know which exact property you used to split $\sum_{j=i+1}^n j $ into $\sum_{\color{blue}{j=1}}^n j - \sum_{j=1}^{\color{blue}{i}} j$? I'm referencing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#cite_note-:0-7.

Comment: You are welcome. In the part with the blue coloring I just add and subtract $\sum_{j=1}^i j$ in order to use the mentioned formula which is also given on the page you linked.

Comment: @ZeusKrakus : Just added a line to the calculation to show what I did.

Comment: Awesome. For anyone looking it up, the identities that are being applied are splitting a sum, using associativity in order to allow us to subtract out $\sum_{j=1}^i j from \sum_{j=i+1}^n j$; and commutativity and associativity that allow us to add $\sum_{j=1}^i {j} - \sum_{j=1}^i j$ on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

- Set $k = j-i$, so replace all uses of $j$ with $k+i$.
- For the lower bound, subtract $i$ from both sides of the assignment.
- For the upper bound, subtract $i$.  ("... to $k+i = n$ ...".)
- In the summand, simplify $k+i-i$.

This should leave a sum you know how to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't follow why k + i = n for the upper bound. What summation identity is being applied?

Comment: @ZeusKrakus : "$j = i+1$ to $n$" means "$j = i+1$ to $j = n$".  The "$j={}$" is suppressed in the overset (because it is obvious), but it *is* part of the process the notation specifies.